# Using a transaction to insert a record after updating the same table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using raw SQL and trying to do an update *and then* an insert on the same table, do you think I need some type of transaction or something?

If I add an `INSERT` and then an `UPDATE` in the same script file, will the order of the execution be respected by SQL?

Ended up with this so far:

```sql
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM dbo.Settings 
               WHERE Descr = 'GL for Credit Memos')
BEGIN
    SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.Settings ON

    DECLARE @newOrderNo INT;
    SET @newOrderNo = 7 -- OrderNo for credit memo to display below 'GL for A/P'

    -- Update order no. for settings below 'GL for Credit Memo'
    UPDATE dbo.Settings 
    SET [OrderNo] = [OrderNo] + 1 
    WHERE [OrderNo] >= @newOrderNo

    INSERT INTO [dbo].[Settings]
               ([SettingID],
               [Created],
               [Descr],
               [Category],
               [OrderNo],
               [DataType],
               [InActive],
               [IsRequired])
         VALUES
               (198, -- New Enum value for setting ID for 'Gl for Credit Memo'
               DEFAULT,
               'GL for Credit Memo',
               'Accounting',
               @newOrderNo,
               4,
               NULL,
               1)
    
    SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.Settings OFF
END
```

Comment: What exactly are you asking? If you have any plans for a future using SQL then I highly recommend learning what transactions are and when to use them.

Comment: Of course the order of execution is respected... what coding language do you know which re-orders statements?

Comment: I was wondering if there could be a potential issue by using an `UPDATE` followed by an `INSERT` on the same file, since i'm not sure if the order of execution will be respected. Hence, asking if I need a transaction to make sure that the `INSERT` occurs _after_ the `UPDATE`.

Comment: @DaleK I'm new to SQL and I was not sure if the order would be respected. I read about transactions and it confused me. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: 1) Not sure what you mean when you refer to a "file" databases have tables? 2) Of course the order of statements is respected, what would make you think otherwise? 3) A transaction has nothing to do with the order of statements anyway, it just ensures all or nothing.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. By "file" I mean this is a release script that would be attached to a PR.

Comment: I would definitely use a transaction, because you do want ""ALL OR NOTHING" behaviour. You don't want the update to success and the insert to fail. But thats nothing to do with the ordering of the statements.

Comment: @DaleK Given that SQL reorders everything *within* a statement, including things like `OR` short-circuiting which no other language does, it's a fair question for a beginner to ask if the rest of the batch might be reordered or interleaved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whole statements in SQL are always executed in order. There is no reordering except within a single statement (for example the order that rows may be updated in a single `UPDATE` is undefined).

You probably **do** want a transaction here, if you want to ensure that the code works in an "all-or-nothing" fashion.

But you do not need any complex catch/rolback code. Contrary to popular opinion, it is almost never necessary, and usually actively harmful.

The only thing you need to do, and this you **must** do to ensure proper rollbacks, is to use `XACT_ABORT`. This tells the server to ensure a rollback will always happen, regardless of any errors.

```sql
SET XACT_ABORT ON;

BEGIN TRANSACTION;

-- your code here

COMMIT;
```

If you are executing in SSMS then you will see any errors. If executing from a client app or script, you can catch the error in the *client* app, then show the error to the user and/or log it.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server, autocommit transactions are turned on by default during installation. That means that for most servers, each individual SQL statement opens a transaction in the background, executes, and then commits the transaction if the statement succeeds or rolls it back if the statement fails, all behind the scenes.

You can override that behavior by issuing a `BEGIN TRANSACTION` statement, which will open a transaction and keep it open until you issue an explicit `COMMIT TRANSACTION` or `ROLLBACK` statement. Usually the `ROLLBACK` will live in the `CATCH` clause of a `TRY...CATCH`. Everything between those explicit statements will be treated as a single transaction.

In your case, the `UPDATE` will be in one transaction and the `INSERT` will be in another.

Here's the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-implicit-transactions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16).